# I cannot figure out where to change the font on my wordpress theme

Tags: fonts

I have never had this issue before but I recently took over management of a site HomesUSAAlliance.com and wanted to consolidate and update the fonts. I went to the Style.css file in the theme and added the custom font style but nothing happened. That's when I went to the site to see where the font style was being directed from and found:
http://www.homesusaalliance.com/wp-content/themes/kleo/assets/css/custom/style.css?ver=3.1.3

I cannot seem to find this document anywhere in my actual Wordpress admin site and am lost. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

While technically the answer from Jonny Perl is accurate, it's **not** a good idea to directly edit your theme's files. Any changes you make will get overwritten with a theme update.

Instead, create a Child Theme (lots of articles on how to do that), and add your CSS code in the Child Theme's style.css file.

You could change the default theme with a CSS `body` command, changing the `font-family` used. It may be that you will need to add several CSS styles for `font-family`, depending on how your theme is built. You can use developer tools (like Firebug) to figure out the CSS used at any part of your site.

Answer (score 0):

This file is within the theme itself and so will be available via the theme editor at yoursite.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php (this assumes a setup with a standard directory structure).

On the right you'll see a list of files in your theme, and WordPress will list out files in subdirectories too.

For this file it will say something like: 
**Stylesheet
(assets/css/style.css)**. Click on this file and it will come up in the editor.